# Sample solutions for low-level problems written in C

Tags: c

Does anyone know where I might find sample solutions written in C for low level / systems level applications? A really good website or book recommendation would be cool too.

I've learned some of the basics, but would like to see some code within the context of a real solution written in C, and specifically for a lower-level problem. Id' be interested in how C is used within the context of OS programming, for example. What are some areas where C is used for lower-level programming?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: How does downloading the Linux kernel and looking at a specific subsytem sound? E.g. the memory manager, or the scheduler, or some device driver?

Comment: You can have a look at the linux kernel (or read a book about it).

Comment: Do you know of any programming languages (interpreters / compilers) that are written in C? Or do they all use an even lower-level language typically, like assembly.

Comment: @SeanThoman: Python, Ruby, PHP are written in C (however there are some other implementations like IronPython or JRuby).

Comment: Perl is written in C as well, I believe.

Comment: "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way". Well thats specific -- apparently this doesn't qualify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to study MINIX3 from Tanenbaum: http://www.minix3.org/

Its a microkernel architecture, and with his book ( http://vig.prenhall.com/catalog/academic/product/0,1144,0131429388,00.html ) it is really enlightning.

As of my opinion, studying the linux kernel is a bit hardcore for a start ;), and out of a academical point of view the microkernel architecture is superior to the monolithic kernel.

Furthermore, with only a few thousands lines of code, unlike the Linux Kernel, its consumable in a realistic timetable.

And its a real serious project, the European Union sponsored some Millions towards it as far as i am aware of. I think i remind him saying that in one of his talks.

And you have a X-Server running there, a gcc-toolchain etcpp.

Have fun :)

EDIT: As i read the comments, someone mentions the Ruby interpreter. Its written in a mixture of C and Ruby, and as far as it was mentioned in one episode of se-radio.net, it is really nice sourcecode. Though i have to admit, i havent looked into it myself. Might be worth the dig into it if you have some interest in Ruby too.

Comment: All good answers but chose this one b/c its a simplified operating system, and I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at some (for you) interesting open source projects written in C. For example, there's [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/), a piece of software that runs on embedded devices and has lots of smaller programs to study. You could, for example, take the source for the [telnet client](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/telnet.c) on one side and the [corresponding RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html) on the other. Or, for a steeper learning curve, you could also try studying the open source OSes, like the [Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org/) ([here's](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree) the tree for browsing) or the BSDs. It's a lot more involved than busybox, but you can still find some parts that are fairly easy to understand if you're familiar with the context.

Answer (score 1):

- Studying the Linux kernel, maybe in conjunction with one of the several books on the kernel or device drivers would provide a wealth of material.  Much of this is available free.
- any or all of the books by [W. Richard Stevens](http://www.kohala.com/start/) that walk though the implementation (TCP/IP Illustrated) or use (UNIX Network Programming) of the networking stack or his Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment book.

If you have a leaning toward Windows there are several good books, even if they're quite old, including:

- [Programming Server-Side Applications for Microsoft Windows 2000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735607532) by Richter and Clark
- [Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572319968) by Richter

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following sources might be interesting r.e. Operating Systems from a learning perspective. Be aware there have been many advancements actually present in modern kernels:

- The [original linux code](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/).
- [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/xv6/). This is a simple unix OS that goes along with [MIT's excellent OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) course on [Operating Systems](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2006/).

Other ideas:

- [The current grub stage 1 bootloader](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/grub/trunk/grub/annotate/head:/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S) isn't that complicated - it's pretty hard to be complicated with 512 bytes to play with.
- The [Linux kernel module guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/) gives you an introduction to building kernel modules. You could experiment with building custom, yet pointless, drivers that add say character devices to `/dev/` or proc devices to `/proc` and work towards implementing something interesting. People have implemented web servers in kernel space...
- If you want to experiment with Windows kernels, have a go with [Native NT applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx). I'd start with printing a pointless boot message, then move up to drivers.

Beyond that, it's hard to suggest where you might want to go. Systems level is a wide space.

In the context of low level programming, C and C++ are portable assembler. In many of the above spaces the standard library is either partially or totally missing and extra functionality may be implemented by existing parts of the system-level code you're modifying, so you have to be aware of the API functions available to you in any given space and what you need to implement yourself, as well as what your memory and processing requirements must be. For example, a bootloader written to the MBR has to use bios interrupts and starts in real (16-bit) mode. Those are the constraints of the hardware design. Likewise, functions like `fopen()` aren't available in kernel space since they wrap system calls - you'd need to use kernel specific constructs to achieve this if it really made sense to write a file from kernel space.